# Why does this for loop run infinitely after recieving input? (Java)

Tags: java, hashmap

Okay so this code asks the user to enter a name, year, and gender, and displays the ranking of the name for the selected year. It reads data from the url and places it into a map for each year. These maps are then placed into an array, and finally the rank is displayed to the user. My program never finishes running after entering the while loop. Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Map[] boyArray = new Map[10];
    Map[] girlArray = new Map[10];
    System.out.print("Enter year (between 2001 and 2010): ");
    String year = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter gender (M or F): ");
    String gender = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter name: ");
    String name = input.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Map<String, String> boys = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, String> girls = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL("http://www.cs.armstrong.edu/liang/data/babynamesranking"+ year + ".txt");
            Scanner urlInput = new Scanner(url.openStream());
            while (urlInput.hasNext()) {
                String rank = input.next();
                boys.put(urlInput.next(), rank);
                urlInput.next();
                girls.put(input.next(), rank);
                urlInput.next();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
        }
        boyArray[i] = boys;
        girlArray[i] = girls;
    }
    if (gender.charAt(0) == 'M') {
        System.out.println("The name " + name + " was ranked " + boyArray[Integer.parseInt(year) - 2001].get(name) + " in " + year);
    } else {
        System.out.println("The name " + name + " was ranked " + girlArray[Integer.parseInt(year) - 2001].get(name) + " in " + year);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: String rank = input.next(); <- looks like you want urlInput. Same applies to girls.put(input.next(), rank);

Comment: Wow thank you so much! I can't believe I didn't notice that. I've been stuck on this for hours lol. It works now!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, as @uthark has already noted, your program is waiting for input because in your `while` loop you're waiting for input from `System.in` with the line `String rank = input.next();` (and the line `girls.put(input.next(), rank);`).  You probably meant to write `String rank = urlInput.next();` and `girls.put(urlInput.next(), rank);` instead so that the rank and girl name come from `http://www.cs.armstrong.edu/liang/data/babynamesranking`YYYY`.txt`.